# LDR Rd,-Label vs LDR Rd,[PC+Offset]

Tags: c, assembly, iar

I am new to IAR and Embedded Programming. I was debugging the following C code, and found that `R0` gets to hold the address of `counter1` through `??main_0`, while `R1` gets to hold address of `counter2` through `[PC,#0x20]`. This is completely understandable, but I cannot get why it was assigned to `R0` to use `LDR Rd, -label` while `R1` used `LDR Rd, [PC+Offset]` and what is the difference between the two approaches?

I only knew about literal pools after searching but It didn't answer my question. In addition, where did `??main_0` get defined in the first place?

[image: IAR Disassembler]

```
int counter1=1;
int counter2=1;
int main()
{
    int *ptr;
    int *ptr2;
    ptr=&counter1;
    ptr2=&counter2;
 
    ++(*ptr);
    ++(*ptr2);
 
    ++counter2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`??main_0` is not "defined" as such, it's just an auto-generated label for the address used here so that when reading the disassembly you don't have to remember that address `0x8c` is that counter pointer. In fact it would make sense to have the other counter pointer as `??main_1` and I'm not sure why it shows the bare `[PC, #0x20]` instead. As you can see on page 144/145 of the [IAR assembly reference](https://wwwfiles.iar.com/arm/webic/doc/EWARM_AssemblerReference.ENU.pdf), those two forms are just different interpretations of the same machine code. If the disassembler decides to assign a label to an address, it can show the label form, otherwise the offset form.

The machine code of the first instruction is `48 07`, which means `LDR.N R0, [PC, #0x1C]`. The interpretation as `??main_0` (and the assignment of a label `??main_0` to address `0x8c` in the first place) is just something the disassembler decided to do. You cannot know what the original assembly source (if it even exists and the compiler didn't directly compile to machine code) looked like and whether it used a label there or not.